# How to remove white space characters from string in Python

Tags: python

While declaring `argString` variable I use white spaces to format a code so it is easy to read later. So instead of typing:

```
argString="""
line1
line2
line3
"""
```

I am using this instead:

```
argString="""
    line1
    line2
    line3
"""
```

The problem I have encounter is that later when `argString` is written to output text file the extra white spaces used to format code are still preserved and written to the output text file. So the resulted output text file is written in a form:

```
....line1
....line2
....line3
```

(where each period '.' represents white space character.

How to remove the extra white spaces used purely for the code readability when a content of the string variable `argString` is written to the text file?

```
import tempfile

argString="""
    line1
    line2
    line3
"""
writeFile=tempfile.mkdtemp()+'/script.txt'

_file=open(writeFile, "wb")
_file.write(argString)
_file.close()
```

Comment: If you remove all whitespace then you'll end up removing the newlines too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent):

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> argString="""
...     line1
...     line2
...     line3
... """
>>> print textwrap.dedent(argString)

line1
line2
line3

>>>
```

You might actually want to strip the leading and trailing newlines:

```
>>> print textwrap.dedent(argString).strip()
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: Nice, didn't even know such a module existed! (+1)

Comment: @NPE -- Well, If I can show _you_ something new then I think I have already had a very successful day!  :-).

Comment: If I am shown something new then I think I have already had a very successful day! Thanks!